# MATLAB UI interface and coding issue

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-guide

I'm having this issue in my MATLAB program.
I want to perform a `set` operation on my UI during a coding. In other words I'm pressing a button to launch my code and at the same time I want to change some `uicontrol`s.
I tried with `pause` and `wait` with no luck.
I'm pretty sure that MATLAB gives priority to my coding part intead of the Java interface.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a drawnow?

Comment: @Nick thank you it worked perfectly. Actually I can now solve some other tiny bugs of my code. Thank you so much again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to nick I solved adding

```
waitnow; pause(.1);
```

Guys, unbelievable, that works on linux/OSX but not under windows..that's so weird